# twitter bootstrap accordion IE 9 troubles with selectbox

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

I'm using angularJS with twitter bootstrap. in my html page i'm using accordion and in the content of the accordion I have a select box. it works fine with firfox, ie10, chrome ... but in IE9 it cuts off the text in the select box. it only shows the first letter of the text of the preselected value. if i click in the select box, i can see the whole text.

can anybody tell me, how to fix this problem? it seems to be a problem with the accordion, because if i put the selectbox outside of the accordion, the selectbox also works in IE9.

Comment: did you find a solution to your problem? I am running into the same issue here

Comment: sorry...no i still have this problem

Answer (score 0):

I ran into a similar issue (AngularJS 1.2.x) where the select dropdown was defined with a single empty "Please select" option, and then was updated with values returned from a REST API; it then would select an initial value according to data received from another subsequent REST call, all upon page load.

I think all the async updating confused IE9's rendering of the select box (the rendering of your accordion component probably resulted in a similar situation). In our case it would basically maintain the visible text width of the initial 'Please select' option, cutting off the longer newly selected initial item (although it would rerender and resolve itself if the user interacted with the control).

Managed to resolve by, in IE9, adding a space to the end of the selected option's text, triggering a re-render of it. Used code similar to the following, which extends angular's built-in select directive:

```
(function() {
  "use strict";

  angular.module('ngBrowserFixes', [])
    .config(['$provide', Decorate]);

  function Decorate($provide) {

    if(window.navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE 9") !== -1) {
      $provide.decorator('selectDirective',
        ['$delegate', '$timeout', selectDirectiveDecorator]);
    }

    function selectDirectiveDecorator($delegate, $timeout) {
      var directive = $delegate[0],
        link = directive.link;

      directive.compile = function newCompile() {
        return function newLink(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          link.apply(this, arguments);
          var option;

          $timeout(addSpace, 0, false);

          // adding a space to the selected option forces ie9 to
          // do a re-render at the correct width
          function addSpace() {
            if(element[0].selectedIndex === -1) {
              return;
            }

            //options weren't available prior to the timeout delay
            option = element[0].options[element[0].selectedIndex]; 
            option.text += " ";
            scope.$evalAsync(removeSpace);
          }

          // tidy up (optional)
          function removeSpace() {
            option.text = option.text.replace(/\s+$/, '');
          }
        };
      };

      return $delegate;
    }

  }
})();
```